# Redshift - Insert data into a temp table with a condition being column doc_id should be unique and not null

Tags: redshift

I'm trying to create a temp table and insert data into it in Redshift.
My goal is to create a single record for **unique** doc_id WHERE doc_id **IS NOT NULL**.

Here's my code:

```
-- Creating temp table to load only rows with unique and not null doc_id
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_table CASCADE;

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP_table
(
    uuid varchar,
    id integer,
    doc_id integer,
    revenue double,
    doc_date varchar,
);

-- insert into the temp table and add the distinct and not null filter on the doc_id
INSERT INTO TMP_table
(
    uuid,
    id,
    doc_id,
    revenue,
    doc_date
)
SELECT
    uuid,
    id,
    select DISTINCT (table_x.doc_id) from table_x where table_x.doc_id IS NOT NULL,
    revenue,
    doc_date
FROM schema.table_x;
```

Upon running the above code I get a syntax error near distinct. And I can't seem to figure out what the error is.

Any guidance please?

Comment: So what do you want to happen if in that `table_x` there are two or more rows with the same `doc_id` value?

Comment: Skip both of them - and proceed to insert only rows that doc_id exists only once? Insert one of the (two or more rows with same doc_id) at random? Fail the whole INSERT and do no inserts at all?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ If there are duplicates doc_ids I just want to pick one and insert it (it should be not null too thus my where statement)

Comment: @GeoSal what is the version of Redshift and does it have window functions, eg `ROW_NUMBER()`? It can be done without it but it would simplify the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there are duplicates doc_ids I just want to pick one and insert it (it should be not null too thus my where statement).

You can use a window/ranking function - eg. `ROW_NUMBER()` - to simplify the query.

Note: I haven't checked if these are available in Redshift.

```
INSERT INTO TMP_table
(
    uuid,
    id,
    doc_id,
    revenue,
    doc_date
)
SELECT 
    uuid,
    id,
    doc_id,
    revenue,
    doc_date
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        uuid,
        id,
        doc_id,
        revenue,
        doc_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER          -- assign row numbers
          ( PARTITION BY doc_id    -- per doc_id
                                   -- without any specific order
          ) AS rn
    FROM schema.table_x
    WHERE doc_id IS NOT NULL 
  ) AS x
WHERE rn = 1    -- pick the first one per doc_id if there are 2+ 
;
```

Comment: On the query above, I can see that we added to the select subquery a ROW_NUMBER() maybe this is the added column that's causing an issue? Is is added as a new column?

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126606/discussion-between-ypercube-and-geosal)**